# Is it possible to import .pyo files

Tags: python

Well,

Is it possible to import "os" module with "os.pyo" or "os.pyc" instead of "os.py"?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  If you started Python without `-O` you'll need the `.pyc` file, and with `-O` you will need `.pyo`.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know. Even the doc is ambiguous about this one. See http://bugs.python.org/issue12982